# Setting gravity for SceneKit ParticleEngine particles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, gravity

I'm just experimenting with SceneKit as a continuing migration through methods of 3D rendering.  I have played with SceneKit and it is generally as advertised.  One troublesome aspect (for me) is that while I can create ParticleEngines via the UI or code, I can't figure out how  to set the gravitational field for particles created via code.

The working code is here: https://github.com/rkwright/ParticleTest.  Works with XCode 12.3 and iOS 15.3

Here is the function that sets up the ParticleEngine via code.

```
func createTrailCode( color: UIColor ) -> SCNParticleSystem {

    let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
    particleSystem.birthRate = 5000
    particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 1
    particleSystem.warmupDuration = 1
    particleSystem.emissionDuration = 500.0
    particleSystem.loops = false
    particleSystem.particleColor = color
    particleSystem.particleSize = 0.25
    particleSystem.birthDirection = .random
    particleSystem.speedFactor = 7
    particleSystem.emittingDirection = SCNVector3(0,1,1)
    particleSystem.emitterShape = .some(SCNSphere(radius: 2.0))
    particleSystem.spreadingAngle = 30
    particleSystem.particleImage = "star"
    particleSystem.isAffectedByGravity = true
    particleSystem.acceleration = SCNVector3(0.0,-1.8,0.0)
    
    return particleSystem
```

If you run the demo you'll see the ParticleEngine created from the scnp file works fine and the particles  slowly drop as they are pulled by gravity.  But for the engine created with code (above) the particles immediately zoom off the scene, no matter what the gravity or acceleraton is set to.

Still poking at this, but any suggestions would be appreciated.  TIA

Comment: I downloaded and quickly tested your project on GitHub. As I can see, in the SCNP File the Particle attribute gravity is not even checked. And the Particles go down because you set Y Acceleration to a negative value. Try to make both systems exactly the same - code and scnf file can confige all aspects needed for a great particle system. Also check you physics world settings for a correct gravity of your scene. (PS: I made this app here: https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/working-fire/id1528141986 and it is not using any scnp file. Everything goes trough one single particle system written in code)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’ll have a go. Is the code for your app available e.g. on github?

Comment: Well, I have tweaked all the values to try and set them to the same values as the SCNP file.  But no luck.  Could you indicate how I should set the fields in code to match the SCNP behaviour?  TIA

Comment: AH.  With some further tweaking at a lot of time poking around I got it all to work.  (in github)  Both the SCNP and the code approach produce the same output... almost.  However the SCNP trail stars are the same size initially but shrink over time while the code trail stars do not.  This turns out to be because somewhere along the line an action was inserted in the trail.scnp the performs this action.  One can see it in the debugger.  I'm going to start a new query about this.

Comment: I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958867/xcode-11-action-editor-how-to-invoke/65966215#65966215